# Passing Variables Into an 'onchange' method ASP.NET Entity Framework

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm attempting to pass a DateTime variable from a @Html.EditorFor to a JavaScript function but am getting an error.

My current line is looped through multiple times so needs to be unique but is:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Periods[i].EndTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = $"endTime {i}", onchange = $"checkChanged({Model.Periods[i].EndTime})" } })
```

Linking to a JavaScript function of:

```
 function checkChanged(newTime) {
            console.log(newTime);
}
```

When i run this code and change the text box, i am getting a console error of *Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list* but the call is receiving the date. https://imgur.com/a/WlE9y

Comment: You are passing in a date to `checkChanged` but you forgot to add quotes around it.

Comment: ive added single quotes around it but it thinks its a string and returns this: Model.Periods[i].StartTime.
Current code is now: onchange = 
 $"checkChanged('Model.Periods[i].EndTime')"

Comment: All solved. Thanks alot and posting code as a solution!

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the single quotes so final answer is:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Periods[i].StartTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = $"startTime {i}", onchange = $"checkChanged('{Model.Periods[i].StartTime}')" } })
```